# Message published but never reached the broker

Tags: spring-amqp

My rabbit template is configured to use CachingConnectionFactory with
cache mode connection. In rare cases when calling

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend
```

it passes without any issue but the message never got the rabbitmq broker.

Few seconds after that, another thread logs:
An unexpected connection driver error occured
and stacktrace:
com.rabbitmq.client.MissedHeartbeatException: Heartbeat missing with heartbeat = 60 seconds

Is there a config that I should activate to be sure that message has got the broker or at least I expect an exception to be thrown in the sending thread?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to turn on *Publisher Confirms and Returns* on the `CachingConnectionFactory` and `mandatory` for the `RabbitTemplate`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/#cf-pub-conf-ret